# Serving a file inside TAR archive using Nginx

Tags: http, nginx, tar

As you may know. TAR archive store files in their original shape. so in order to serve files inside TAR archive using Nginx, only an offset value and file length should be given to Nginx. 
How can i give Nginx offset and content length ? 
And have a link like this:

`http://example.com/Archive.tar/path/to/file.bin`

Also note that i need nginx to accept Range header and be able to serve it respectfully

Comment: Some kind of pre-processing is required, have you tried a backend (https://golang.org/pkg/archive/tar/) proxied via Nginx?

Comment: i tried python with nginx/uWsgi, it worked. but i want nginx to handle file delivery. not a python(or any other language) loop.

Comment: Makes sense, have you tried http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom nginx module if you don't want to use any CGI script.

Follow this guide: http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html